# iOS 10 - NavigationBar NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

The method causing the crash:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false) // <- Line the crash happens
}
```

The crash description:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please file a radar on
>   UIKit if you see this assertion.

---

Note, this crash only appears on iOS 10. When running with iOS 11 the code functions as expected. Has anyone experience this issue or does anyone know of any workaround?

Comment: A couple things I'd try. First try moving the setNavigationBarHidden call before the call to super.viewWillDisappear. The super implementation might be interfering somehow with what you're trying to do. If that doesn't work I'd move setNavigationBarHidden into viewWillAppear in the view controller that will be appearing when the controller you currently have displayed is dismissed. I'm guessing you have a controller presented on another, and want the nav bar displayed when the top controller is dismissed.

Comment: @digitalHound Unfortunately none of those suggestions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the following line in my `AppDelegate` that was causing problems.

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).title = ""
```

Taking this out fixed the problem for iOS 10.